# Python3 ImportError. can't solved by any previous way

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

**Trying to import other classes from another folder. Getting import error again and again...
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
How can I get rid of it??
I have **init**.py in "modules" folder, but that's also not helping........**

- Codes in "modules" folder:
- snake.py

  ```
  import pygame
  from pathlib import *
  base_directory = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
  object_size = 40  # ! dimension of object image. choose a squire sized image.

  class Snake:
   def __init__(self, parent_screen, snake_size):
       self.parent_screen = parent_screen
       self.snake_directory = 'resources/block.jpg'
       self.full_snake_directory = base_directory / self.snake_directory
       self.snake = pygame.image.load(self.full_snake_directory).convert()

       self.direction = 'right'
       self.snake_size = snake_size
       self.snake_x = [object_size]*snake_size
       self.snake_y = [object_size]*snake_size

   def draw_snake(self):
       for size in range(self.snake_size):
           self.parent_screen.blit(self.snake, (self.snake_x[size], self.snake_y[size]))
       pygame.display.flip()

   def move_left(self):
       self.direction = 'left'

   def move_right(self):
       self.direction = 'right'

   def move_up(self):
       self.direction = 'up'

   def move_down(self):
       self.direction = 'down'

   def walk_snake(self):
       for position in range(self.snake_size-1, 0, -1):
           self.snake_x[position] = self.snake_x[position-1]
           self.snake_y[position] = self.snake_y[position-1]

       if self.direction == 'left':
           self.snake_x[0] -= object_size
       elif self.direction == 'right':
           self.snake_x[0] += object_size
       elif self.direction == 'up':
           self.snake_y[0] -= object_size
       elif self.direction == 'down':
           self.snake_y[0] += object_size

       self.draw_snake()

   def increase_snake_size(self):
       self.snake_size += 1
       self.snake_x.append(-1)
       self.snake_y.append(-1)
  ```
- food.py

  ```
  import pygame
  from pathlib import *
  import random

  base_directory = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
  object_size = 40  # ! dimension of object image. choose a squire sized image.

  class Food:
     def __init__(self, parent_screen):
     self.parent_screen = parent_screen
     self.food_directory = 'resources/apple.jpg'
     self.full_food_directory = base_directory / self.food_directory
     self.food = pygame.image.load(self.full_food_directory).convert()
     self.food_x = object_size * 3
     self.food_y = object_size * 3

  def draw_food(self):
     self.parent_screen.blit(self.food, (self.food_x, self.food_y))
     pygame.display.flip()

  def move_food(self):
     self.food_x = random.randint(0, 26) * object_size
     self.food_y = random.randint(0, 18) * object_size
  ```
- Code in the main folder: game.py

  ```
  import pygame
  from pygame.locals import *
  from pathlib import *
  from .modules import snake
  from .modules import food
  import time

  base_directory = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
  object_size = 40  #! dimension of object image. choose a squire sized image.
  text_color = (232, 93, 4)

  class Game:
     def __init__(self):
       pygame.init()
       pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Game by ZamaaN')

       pygame.mixer.init()
       self.play_background_music('bg_music_1')

       self.window_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((1102, 786))
       self.snake = snake.Snake(self.window_surface, 1)
       self.snake.draw_snake()
       self.food = food.Food(self.window_surface)

       #? Food appears over snake.
       for positon in range(self.snake.snake_size):
           if self.is_hit(self.food.food_x, self.food.food_y, self.snake.snake_x[positon], self.snake.snake_y[positon]):
               self.food.draw_food()

      def is_hit(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        if x1 >= x2 and x1 < x2 + object_size:
           if y1 >= y2 and y1 < y2 + object_size:
               return True
        return False

      def display_score(self):
         font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 28)
         score = font.render(f'Score: {self.snake.snake_size - 1}', True, text_color)

         self.window_surface.blit(score, (995, 11))

      def play_background_music(self, sound_name):
         sound_directory = f'resources/{sound_name}.mp3'
         full_ding_directory = base_directory / sound_directory
         pygame.mixer.music.load(full_ding_directory)
         pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

      def play_sound(self, sound_name):
         sound_directory = f'resources/{sound_name}.mp3'
         full_ding_directory = base_directory / sound_directory
         sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(full_ding_directory)
         pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound)

     def render_background(self):
         background_directory = 'resources/background.jpg'
         full_background_directory = base_directory / background_directory
         background = pygame.image.load(full_background_directory)
         self.window_surface.blit(background, (0, 0))

     def play(self):
         self.render_background()
         self.snake.walk_snake()
         self.food.draw_food()
         self.display_score()
         pygame.display.flip()

         #? Snake eat food.
         if self.is_hit(self.snake.snake_x[0], self.snake.snake_y[0], self.food.food_x, self.food.food_y):
            self.play_sound('ding')
            self.snake.increase_snake_size()
            self.food.move_food()

         #? Snake eat itself.
         for positon in range(1, self.snake.snake_size):
            if self.is_hit(self.snake.snake_x[0], self.snake.snake_y[0], self.snake.snake_x[positon], self.snake.snake_y[positon]):
               self.play_sound('crash')
               raise 'Game Over!'

         #? Snake hit the boundries of the window
         if not (0 <= self.snake.snake_x[0] <= 1102 and 0 <= self.snake.snake_y[0] <= 786):
              self.play_sound('crash')
              raise "Game Over!"

     def display_game_over(self):
         self.render_background()

         font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 28)
         score = font.render(f'Game is Over! Score: {self.snake.snake_size - 1}', True, text_color)
         self.window_surface.blit(score, (200, 300))

         continue_message = font.render('To play again press Enter. To exit press Escape!', True, text_color)
         self.window_surface.blit(continue_message, (200, 350))
         pygame.display.flip()

         pygame.mixer.music.pause()

    def reset(self):
        self.snake = snake.Snake(self.window_surface, 1)
        self.food = food.Food(self.window_surface)

    def run(self):
        running = True
        pause = False

        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
               if event.type == KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                   running = False

               if event.key == K_RETURN:
                   pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                   pause = False

               if not pause:
                   if event.key == K_LEFT:
                       self.snake.move_left()

                   if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                       self.snake.move_right()

                   if event.key == K_UP:
                       self.snake.move_up()

                   if event.key == K_DOWN:
                       self.snake.move_down()

              elif event.type == QUIT:
               running = False

           try:
             if not pause:
               self.play()
           except Exception as e:
             self.display_game_over()
             pause = True
             self.reset()

          time.sleep(0.24)


   if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing

```
from .modules import
```

Try

```
from modules import
```

Also add __init__.py in main folder as well

Comment: without . it's not accepting, __init__py added

Comment: after removing dot, it's working. error showing only by kite, I will uninstall it